# How to compile PHP extension without debug?

Tags: php

I made a PHP extension with PHP 7.0.11.

But this PHP extension cannot load as below:

```
[root@linux01 ~]# php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: xxxxx_library: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20151012,NTS,debug
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20151012,NTS
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

How to compile PHP extension without debug?

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this problem by myself.
I made this php extension with debug mode of php.
After that, I installed php without debug.
Cache files with debug were left.
So, I ran "make clean all" and "make install".
Thank you.